# Cast MyClass<T> to MyClass<dynamic>

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, casting

The follow code does not compile:

```
public class Test
{
    public void Run()
    {
        List<MyClass<dynamic>> listOfMyClasses = new List<MyClass<dynamic>>();

        MyClass<dynamic> myClass = new MyClass<int>(); // Error here

        listOfMyClasses.Add(myClass);
    }

    public class MyClass<T>
    {
        public void DoSomething() { }
        public void DoSomethingSpecial<T>(T t) { }
    }
}
```

However, I believe it makes sense logically (please let me know if I'm mistaken). Presumably it is useful, for I can call `DoSomething` without knowing the type parameter. How can I accomplish the addition of `myClass` to the list?

Comment: If `MyClass` doesn't actually use the generic parameter, then *remove the generic parameter*.

Comment: It is a condensed example... obviously.

Comment: i could be wrong but I believe generics require specific types and cannot be dynamic or rather ambiguous

Comment: @Edward `dynamic` is a perfectly valid generic type argument.

Comment: @thethuthinnang So condensed that we have almost no clue of what you really want to do. **Obviously, the way to solve a problem usually depends on the details.** So keeping all information for yourself is egocentric.

Comment: Why are people not OK with abstract questions? I gave exactly enough information to answer the question. I am interested in language details, etc., not just how to get the job done. If I was just interested in how to get the job done, I wouldn't be asking this question, I would just use Gusman's approach below.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a list of `MyClass<dynamic>` just use a List of `dynamic`:

```
    public void Run()
    {
        List<dynamic> listOfMyClasses = new List<dynamic>();

        dynamic myClass = new MyClass<int>();

        listOfMyClasses.Add(myClass);
    }

    public class MyClass<T>
    {
        public void DoSomething() { }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I realize this can be done, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @thethuthinnang And what is the question? What is the purpose of mixing generics and dynamics? Obviously, what you are trying does not works but since it is not clear what you really want to do, any answer we would made would be as useless as the question is in the current incomplete state. You expect us to help you while providing so little information on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The question was rather specific and I actually expect people who don't appreciate the question to just move on. Again, the question is how to add `myClass` to `listOfMyClasses` (use my definitions of course). If that can't be accomplished in any way whatsoever, then feel free to add that as an answer.